# How to stop reloading server images in collection view while scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a collection view with images. Lets say, it have 30 images. 
Whenever I scroll the view, the image reloads. It is because, whenever I scroll, this function is called.

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

Now my issue is: I fetch few images from facebook and few from an array. So whenever I scroll, the images from fb alone reloads. How can I stop reloading those images.

Here's my code for displaying image(from fb and local):

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(searchURL) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in
        if let data = responseData{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.image!.image = UIImage(data: data)
                if(cell.image!.image == nil){
                    let strid : String = friendInfo.Friendfb_id;
                    let facebookProfileUrl = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(strid)/picture?type=large")
                    cell.image!.url = facebookProfileUrl;
                }else{
                    cell.image!.url = searchURL;
                }
            })
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

I have also set `prepareForReuse` in the cell:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.imageView.image = nil
}
```

Comment: Add a dictionary having same count data as you collection view . add one param reload : true/ false . based on this load the url in cellForRowAtIndexPath .

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a cache of some sort to cache the images, so when the same cell is displayed for the second time the image should be loaded from cache not from the server. There are multiple solutions for implementing a cache like this, my personal favorite is using [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) to load the images. It does the loading and caching for you.